# Run PostgreSQL on log in on Windows 10 when installed with scoop

Tags: windows, windows-10, postgresql, scoop

I installed PostgreSQL on Windows 10 using Scoop:

```
scoop install postgresql
```

I can start it with:

pg_ctl.exe start

But how do I make it run automatically on boot or log in?

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution for this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a postgreSQL service by using the register command from pg_ctrl:

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N postgres -D "PATH_TO_DATA_FOLDER"
```

You should replace `PATH_TO_DATA_FOLDER` with the postgreSQL data folder. In scoop with postgreSQL 11.5 it should be located on the following location: `%USERPROFILE%\scoop\apps\postgresql\11.5\data\`.